# How do I dynamically position a SVG ontop of another SVG in React.sj?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, dynamic, position

I am writing a web-app using React.js. I have come to the point where I need to control the position of a note on a bar. I intend having two buttons (one for up, one for down) and have the bar and note be two separate .svg image files that I will somehow draw ontop of each other. Like this:
[SVG note ontop of SVG bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLBMD.png)

So my question is:
How can I draw an SVG ontop of another SVG and control its position (dynamic position)? I have tried using

```
style={{position:'fixed'}}
```

for the note but the formatting gets all messed up.

Edit:
.svg image files.

Comment: When you say SVG, do you mean a `.svg` image file, or a `<svg>` tag/component inline?

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to add that. It's an .svg image file.

Comment: Next time you are asked for clarification, please edit the question instead of commenting.

Answer (score 1):

> A page element with **relative positioning** gives you the control to **absolutely position** children elements inside of it.

If you give the **note** `position: absolute`, you'll be able to position it wherever you want, relative to the parent.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.note {
  positition: absolute;

  /* place note in the top left */
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

See [here](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) for more on this technique.

Here's a snippet using `<div>`s instead of SVGs, run it for an example:

```js
function moveUp() {
  document.getElementById("note").style.top = "0.5rem";
}

function moveDown() {
  document.getElementById("note").style.top = "2.5rem";
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.bar {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.note {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5rem;
  left: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="note" id="note"></div>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <button onclick="moveUp()">up</button>
  <button onclick="moveDown()">down</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`position:absolute` will give you the freedom to position the `<img>` tag freely - *in relation to the next parent element with a `position:relative` property*. For example like this:

```
<div style={{position: 'relative'}}>
   <img src="bar.svg"></img>
   <img src="note.svg" style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        left: x,
        top: y
   }}></img>
```